# matplotlib make selected legend entry invisible

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I want to plot two lines, which both have a label, several times in a for loop yielding several plots. In some of those I want the legend to hold both line entries, in some only the handle and label of the first line, leaving the entry for the second line blank. In all cases I need the legend frame to have the exact same size, leaving a blank space in cases where I don't want the second entry.

In theory I just need to turn the second handle and label invisible. I found some solutions with `Rectangle()` or `Circle()` dummy entries set invisible. However, they don't have the same size as the real legend entry resulting in differing legend frame hight depending on whether I use both lines in the legend or just one line and the dummy. Is there a solution for that?

Here is an example which comes close to what it looks like (despite generating values, of course). Say, in every second iteration I need the lower legend entry to disappear without the legend frame changing its size or shape. How can I do that?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(10):
    x1 = x2 = y1 = y2 = np.random.rand(5)
    yerr1 = yerr2 = .1

    plt.figure()
    plt.errorbar(x1, y1, yerr=yerr1, c='r', ls='-', marker='.', label='set1')
    plt.errorbar(x2, y2, yerr=yerr2, c='k', ls='-', marker='.', label='set2')

    # Get rid of error bars in legend
    ax.gca()
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    handles = [n[0:1] for n in handles]

    plt.legend(handles, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(0.,1.,1.,0.), loc=3, numpoints=2, ncol=1 ,borderaxespad=0., mode='expand', labelspacing=0.5, borderpad=0.2, handletextpad=0.05)
    plt.savefig('test_%d' % i)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Any  example code you have or tried?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the example.

What about something like that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

dummy_white_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='white')

for i in range(10):
    x1 = x2 = y1 = y2 = np.random.rand(5)
    yerr1 = yerr2 = .1

    plt.figure()
    plt.errorbar(x1, y1, yerr=yerr1, c='r', ls='-', marker='.', label='set1')
    plt.errorbar(x2, y2, yerr=yerr2, c='k', ls='-', marker='.', label='set2')

    # Get rid of error bars in legend
    ax = plt.gca()
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

    if i % 2 == 0:

        handles[1] = dummy_white_line
        labels[1]  = ''

    plt.legend(handles, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(0.,1.,1.,0.), 
                loc=3, numpoints=2, ncol=1 ,borderaxespad=0.,
                 mode='expand', labelspacing=0.5, borderpad=0.2, handletextpad=0.05)
    plt.savefig('test_%d' % i)
    #plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

In here I used dummy_white_line to "erase" the line in label (you have white line on white background) and used empty string for a label.

Normal plot:

[image]

Plot without (i.e. empty dummy) second label:

[image: file:///home/marcin/workspace2/mypython/test/test_2.png]

Comment: Thank you. In this minimal example this works exactly as it should. However, in my code the legend height differs very slighty between the two cases, about 5%. Any idea what might cause this? I use `plt.legend()` with the exact same parameters as shown in the example.